# How to get Recently viewed products globally in magento?

Tags: php, magento

I have searched google to get recently viewed products in magento from all users. Then i got following answer to get recently viewed products

```
$collection = Mage::getSingleton('Mage_Reports_Block_Product_Viewed')->getItemsCollection();
```

This collection return only the products which are viewed by that customer only. But I want to get the product collection which are viewed by globally. All the forums have the answer with the above result only. How to get Recently viewed products Globally in magento?

Thank you

Comment: check the link [http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/273724/]

Comment: @MahmoodRehman thank you for your reply. and sorry to late. when i opened that page, i got following error "You are not authorized to perform this action"

Answer (score 0):

Simplest and not so hard for a server capacity is to add EAV attribute in admin named for ex. "viewed" and for each detail showing (you can filter robots etc...) you can write +1 to the number "viewed".
This is good for 1) you can edit it by magento admin, and you can call that number anyway by simple `getViewed()` request. You can sort items by that key on forntend and backend too by default function of Magento and don't need to create new functions.